# MongoDB - Search from multiple collection using multiple parameters

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have to perform a find from multiple collection in MongoDB i.e my query  looks something like below -

```
{
   _id:1003, // This belongs to user collection
   'user.firstName':'xyz', // This belongs to user collection
   'user.lastName':'xyz', // This belongs to user collection
   'member._id':1004,// This belongs to user's family member collection
   'member.firstName':'xyz', // This belongs to member collection
   'member.lastName':'xyz', // This belongs to member collection
}
```

Now I want to support search using multiple parameters i.e a user can search by `user name or member name` or `user name and member name` or `user id or member id` or `user id and member id` or `all of the params`

My question is how do i perform a search from multiple collection using multiple parameters. Any help or pointer would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely not possible. Other than join using $lookup or $graphlookup, i dont think there is any possibility.